# How to execute document ready method in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Can I know how to execute the method using document.ready() as this page do not has a button so I wish to execute when running on the website.I follow the code from the below link. I have cut down some code. Please refer to the link `https://www.quaxio.com/html_white_listed_sanitizer/`

```
    function HtmlWhitelistedSanitizer(escape, tags, css, urls) {
      this.escape = escape;
      this.allowedTags = tags;
      this.allowedCss = css;


    function runSanitizer() {   
      var parser = new HtmlWhitelistedSanitizer(true);
      var sanitizedHtml = parser.sanitizeString(input.value);
      output_as_string.textContent = sanitizedHtml;
      output_as_node.innerHTML = sanitizedHtml;
    }
    source_code.innerText = html_whitelisted_sanitizer.innerText
```

Appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...your code...
});
```

Comment: No, there's should be callback as argument for function `ready()`. You can just put your code inside the function, cause your script will run after page will completely loaded.

Comment: But refer to this link https://www.quaxio.com/html_white_listed_sanitizer/
I just do not know how to start  document ready

Comment: @KhachikHatsagortsyan this code will run after the dom is ready - if you need to wait until completely loaded, you will need to do a `$(window).load` - there is a big dfference between the 2

Comment: @Pete can u tell me the correct way? I`m still stuck.

Comment: @Lawrence, the answer looks correct, just the explanation in the comment was wrong